# iPhone layout to choose when having ads on bottom of the screen? Hamburger menu or bottom tab bar?

Tags: mobile-application, iphone, human-interface-guideline, tab-bar, hamburger

I am working on an iPhone app that needs to have ads at the bottom of the screen.

I am not sure if I should use a hamburger (side) menu or a [tab bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html). In my opinion, the tab bar is the better option, but I am afraid that it could get messy with the ads next to it. Please share your experience and ideas.

Comment: Why do you think that it could get messy with the tab bar? Isn't the tab bar at the top and the advertisement at the bottom?

Comment: Tab bar is at the bottom of the screen, and the ads are also there. so, my concern is that users could to often accidentally click on the ad instead of the tab bar that is used for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend a lot on how many items you intend to link to in a side menu or tab bar. A tab bar [is advised](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html) to contain no more than 5 links so if you can contain yourself within that limit go for the tab bar.

> Displays no more than five tabs at one time in a horizontally compact
>   environment (if there are more tabs, the tab bar displays four of them
>   and adds the More tab, which reveals the additional tabs in a list)

Anymore than that then you should look at other days to display a menu (like the side hamburger menu you mentioned).

Only thing to note is if you do use the tab bar you will need to make sure your ad's are located immediately [above](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/iAdRichMediaAds.html) the tab bar. But from my own experience that seems to be the most consistent place for them as to not distract from the navigation.

Comment: I tend to have 4 items in tab bar. But, that is not my main concern. I would definitely use tab bar, but the problem is that the app uses a lot of ads and position of the ads is just above tab bar. so, my concern is that users could to often accidentally click on the ad instead of the tab bar that is used for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Each option has pros and con:

Hamburger menu : For a lot of item (>5) and no direct navigation on mobile

Bottom tab menu : Maximum 5 items but direct navigation

I advice you to make navigation design and you will see the best way for you level1 navigation